# ¿Por qué no reconoce mi base de datos?

Tags: php, laravel, composer

estoy creando un proyecto laravel, y he creado una base de datos en phpmyadmin. Lo que pasa es que cuando ejecuto mi proyecto laravel con php artisan serve, me aparece lo siguiente: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿A qué se debe?

Comment: si hiciste el proyecto con laravel que pasa cuando mandas el comando migrate?
ya agregaste la coneccion en el .env?

Comment: Lo resolví eliminando la base de datos y volviendo a crearla...